# rel=author and rel=me without Google profile

Tags: google, html, rel, author, google-authorship

Based on the [post at Google Webmasters](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986), a Google profile seems to be needed for `rel=author` to work.

But [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18956/rel-author-and-rel-me-in-wordpress) on our forum does not indicate that.

How do I implement `rel=author` and `rel=me` without any Google profile?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what @JohnConde is saying, he was answering a question about implementing rel=author in wordpress, not how to implement rel=author. You will need the author to have a google profile for this to work as google's own blog suggests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rel=author` is part of HTML5, so you don't have to link it to a Google profile. However Google are saying that if you link it to a Google profile then they may display your picture in search results. They are choosing to use their search engine product to promote their profile product.

[This post](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/06/authorship-markup-and-web-search.html) is more reassuring:

> The markup uses existing standards such as HTML5 (rel=”author”) and
>   XFN (rel=”me”) to enable search engines and other web services to
>   identify works by the same author across the web. If you're already
>   doing structured data markup using microdata from schema.org, we'll
>   interpret that authorship information as well.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not use the `rel=author` or publisher any longer for SEO.